# Apenas consigo alterar a posição "bottom" com "px" e não "%"

Tags: html, css, posicionamento

Estou tentando alterar a posição vertical do parente ".switch", mas apenas o consigo fazer com px e não com %. Como consigo resolver isso?

**HTML**

```
  <label class="switch"> 
     <input type="checkbox">
     <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
```

**CSS**

```
.switch{
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 150px;
}

.switch input{
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.slider{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}


.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só vai funcionar em % se o pai da `label` tiver uma altura definida, pois sem uma altura de referencia vc calcularia o % com base em que?, por isso com % não funciona, pq não tem uma referencia de valor, e com PX vc declara um valor fixo.

No exemplo abaixo eu coloquei sua `label` dentro de uma `div` com altura definida, ai vc pode ver que o `bottom` em % funcionou!

```css
.switch{
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 10%;
}

.switch input{
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.slider{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <label class="switch"> 
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Entendi! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @alexrr10 legal meu caro, fico feliz em ter ajudado!